# Can't access an Amazon S3 item on a public bucket even on admin acct with full permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Utterly mystified. Not sure what I possibly could be missing.

Running into this access denied error:

[image: img2]

This is on an account with FULL admin permissions, including this bit:

[image: img3]

I don't know what I possible could be missing, is there any other reason why this permissions should be blocked.

Comment: A few idea: Was the object possibly copied into that bucket from a different AWS Account? Is your AWS Account part of an AWS Organizations hierarchy? Is there a Bucket Policy on that bucket that includes a `Deny` statement?

Comment: Hi @JohnRotenstein, we aren't part of a hierarchy, nor is there a bucket policy with a deny statement. It might have been copied from a different organization, however. We used a previous AWS org to host our infra!

Comment: But when we open the object, we show up as the user. So I'm not sure what's wrong there.